# learning C++... compiler unexpectedly repeats execution of code at a certain point

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I started learning C++ today and I'm having a tiny bit of trouble..
I'm trying to make a simple program that takes the users age, asks them to enter a number that they would like to increase their age by then outputs the sum of those two numbers..
here it is:

```
#include <iostream>

int getAge()
{
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

cout << "Enter your age: ";
int age;
cin >> age;
cout << endl;
cout << "You are " << age << " years old.";
cout << endl;
return age;
}

int getYearsFromNow()
{
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

cout << endl;
cout << "Enter how many years you want to increase yours age by: ";
int yearsFN;
cin >> yearsFN;
cout << endl << "Increasing your age by " << yearsFN << " years...";
return yearsFN;
}

int main()
{
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

getAge();
getYearsFromNow();

/*int newAge;
newAge = getAge() + getYearsFromNow();
cout << endl << "In " << getYearsFromNow() << " years from now, you will be
" << newAge; */

return 0;
}
```

I have the last part of the main function commented out for testing purposes.. when they are uncommented out, the compiler executes the two calls in the main function (`getAge()` and `getYearsFromNow()`), then does it again, and one more time, and only then does it perform the rest of the code..

I don‘t understand.. I had the last part in a separate function that just returned the variable 'newAge' but that worked out the same..

Comment: Are you aware that each call to `getAge()` or `getYearsFromNow()` re-prompts the user? (It's not as though the program will "remember" and reuse the results of previous calls, if that's what you're thinking.)

Comment: so could i fix that by assigning the two calls to a variable each in main? @ruakh

Answer (score 1):

As user @ruakh pointed out, you are invoking the functions `getAge()` and `getYearsFromNow()` twice:

Once here:

```
getAge();
getYearsFromNow();
```

And again here:

```
newAge = getAge() + getYearsFromNow();
```

What you want to do is save the values returned from the functions the first time around, otherwise the values are effectively being lost. You don't need to call the functions again.

So change your code to the following:

```
int age = getAge();
int yearsFromNow = getYearsFromNow();
int newAge = age + yearsFromNow;
cout << endl << "In " << yearsFromNow << " years from now, you will be " << newAge;
```

Now what's happening is the return value from `getAge()` will be saved to the variable `age` and the return value from `getYearsFromNow()` will be saved to the variable `yearsFromNow`. Now you use these two variables in your calculation and display.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    int age = getAge(); // call only once and assign to a variable
    int years = getYearsFromNow(); // call only once and assign to a variable

    int newAge;
    newAge = age + years;
    cout << endl << "In " << years << " years from now, you will be" << newAge; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not a very helpful answer. You should explain how your code is different.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I actually agree. I got as far as this, and noticed the problem was solved according to the comments in the OP.